# Magento 2.2.4 - Discount Code not working on checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.4, coupon-codes

We have a `discount code` and it works in the `view cart page` but doesn't work in the `checkout/#payment`.

In fact no action is taken when we click on `Apply discount`. Does anybody know the solution for this.

Comment: can you please mention  what type of error you are  getting , or any screenshort .

Comment: When we add a product to the cart and click on CHECKOUT which takes to a page https://colorcherry.com/checkout/#payment   and there is  Apply Discount button and textbox to enter a code and when we enter the code and Apply Discount, nothing happens, the discount code doesn't get applied. But when we VIEW CART instead of CHECKOUT then it takes to a different page and the discount code does work here. But normally customers are not going to click on VIEW CART rather they will just go to CHECKOUT page, apply the discount and progress for payment. So its a big flaw in the process. Can someone help

Comment: Looks like default Magento2 bug you can see the GIT url : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13627